# Sync DuckDuckGo bookmarks between devices?

Tags: browser, privacy, bookmarks

Is it possible to sync DuckDuckGo bookmarks between devices?

I wonder if the reason I haven't found anything is it defeats the main purpose of DDG, being a privacy browser?

Comment: You can import and export the bookmarks, as per the instructions below: [Import/Export Bookmarks](https://www.testingcatalog.com/duckduckgo-now-allows-to-import-and-export-bookmarks-on-android/), [Export Bookmarks](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/apps/apps-duckduckgo-privacy-browser/export-bookmarks/), [Import Bookmarks](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/apps/apps-duckduckgo-privacy-browser/import-bookmarks/). They are basic import and export, like old browsers had before syncing was created. Yes, no cloud storage action due to security concerns, as the poster mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not at the moment. You could leave a review on the Play Store asking them to implement it. Or you can install [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) or [Firefox preview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.fenix) both of which have sync support, as does [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome).

Comment: Mozilla/Firefox sync service, allows to sync among FF mobile, FF preview, FF Focus, FF Quantum (desktop) and Waterfox (desktop and mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Since 14 Feb 2024, DuckDuckGo now offers bookmarks and password sync on Windows, Mac, Android and iPhone: https://spreadprivacy.com/password-sync-backup/

> Now live: **Sync bookmarks, passwords, and Email Protection settings** between DuckDuckGo browsers on phones, tablets, and computers, privately and securely.